# How can I get the equation to print in the correct order?

Tags: java

I'm creating a calculator which has to work out expressions like (12.0 + 10.0) * 3.0. So far I have created the subclasses according to each mathematical operation.

For example:

Addition. java

```
class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression {
Addition(double value1, double value2) {
    result = value1 + value2;
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}
public Addition( ArithmeticExpression an,double num2) {
    value1 = an.evaluate();
    value2 = num2;
    result1 = value1 + value2;
}
public double evaluate1() {
    System.out.println("Arbitrary Answer Is");
    return result1;
}
public double display1() {
    System.out.println("Arbitrary Question Is");
    System.out.println( "(" + value1 + "+"  + value2 + ")" + " =" + result1);
    return result1;
}
public double display() {
    System.out.println("Addition Question Is");
    System.out.println(value1 + " + "+ value2);
    return result;
}
public double evaluate() {
    System.out.println("Addition Answer Is");
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

}

And another for the multiplication which is similar to that but multiplies instead of adding. I then created a class for the question I am answering; the class is below. Arbitrary.java

```
   public class arbitrary {
  public Arbitrary() {
       Addition arbitrary1 = new Addition(12.0,10.0);
       arbitrary1.display1();
       Multiplication arbitrary2 = new Multiplication(arbitrary1,3.0);
       arbitrary2.display2();
}
```

}

When it displays the answer it displays:

Arbitrary Question Is

(12.0+10.0) =0.0

Addition Answer Is

22.0

Arbitrary Question Is

(22.0*3.0) = 66.0

Any suggestions on how I can print out the original question next to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the ArithmeticExpressions instead of evaluated values in the class fields.

Make the 'values' a special subclass of ArithmeticExpressions.

- Note how display is now implemented using

  ```
  System.out.println(expr1.display() + " + "+ expr2.display());
  ```
- evaluate using:

  ```
  double result = expr1.evaluate() + expr2.evaluate();
  ```

Few more hints:

- consider *not* mixing the printing with the evaluation logic (I assume you did this for debugging?)
- consider using/overriding Java's `toString()` instead of `display()`
- consider making a `BinaryExpression` instead of `AdditionExpression`, `MultiplicationExpression`, `SubtractionExpression`, `DivisonExpression` and what operators you have more (`%, ^, ~, !`, etc)

.

```
class LiteralNumberExpression : extends ArithmeticExpression
{
    public double value; 
    LiteralNumberExpression(double v) { this.value = v; }

    public double display() {
        // todo
    }
    public double evaluate() {
        // todo
        return this.value;
    }
}

class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression {
    ArithmeticExpression expr1, expr2;

    Addition(ArithmeticExpression expr1, ArithmeticExpression expr2) {
        this.expr1 = expr1;
        this.expr2 = expr2;
    }
    public string toString() {
        return expr1.display() + " + "+ expr2.display();
    }
    public double evaluate() {
        return expr1.evaluate() + expr2.evaluate();
    }
}
```

Or, the BinaryExpression version:

```
class BinaryExpression extends ArithmeticExpression {
    ArithmeticExpression expr1, expr2;
    char op;

    BinaryExpression(char op, ArithmeticExpression expr1, ArithmeticExpression expr2) {
        this.op = op;
        this.expr1 = expr1;
        this.expr2 = expr2;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + expr1.display() + " " + op + " "+ expr2.display() + ")";
    }
    public double evaluate() {
        switch (op)
        {
            case '+': return expr1.evaluate() + expr2.evaluate();
            case '-': return expr1.evaluate() - expr2.evaluate();
            case '/': return expr1.evaluate() / expr2.evaluate();
            case '*': return expr1.evaluate() * expr2.evaluate();
        }
        throw new // todo exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would parse the operation once and create an enum instead of storing the character - clearer and type safe.

Comment: @Voo by all means. Just drafting the thing up, and not all Java have enums IIRC

Comment: Thanks ive got it working for two numbers but i also need it to work for 3 for example (12+10)*3

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `System.out.println()` statements from your `evaluate()` and `display()` methods.  Instead, override the `toString()` method for each of your operations so it returns only the operands and the operator character -- this will let you nest the operations.  Have the `Arbitrary` class handle all the printing, using the `toString()` of each of your operations.

You might want to create an Identity operation whose purpose is to return whatever argument is provided to it.  That way, you can change the stored values of your `ArithmeticExpression` to `ArithmeticExpression` objects instead of `double`s.  This will help with nested expressions since you won't need to evaluate them until the entire expression is evaluated.

Comment: can you give me an example of how it will look

Answer (score 0):

Define `class MyDouble extends ArithmeticExpression` to wrap a double value.

The constructor of `Addition` and `Mutliplication` should receive two `ArithmeticExpression`.

```
Addition(ArithmeticExpression e1, ArithmeticExpression e2)
```

Replace `display()` of `Addition` with `toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    return "(" + e1.toString() + "+" + e2.toString() + ")";
}
```

Comment: so that is basically my answer, but without the sample.

Comment: i cant replace display i have to have it its part of the assignment

Comment: You can call `System.out.println(toString())` in `display()`. In fact, `display()` should not return `double` since its job is to print the expression.